# Telling a client that there is no result via the DTO pattern

Tags: c#, design-patterns, .net, client

This is how I handle this situation right now:

For example, I have service that returns `UserDto` by user ID: `GetUserById`.

- Service never returns null or throws exceptions.
- Service always returns DTO objects derived from the base class (`DtoBase`).
- Each DTO object relates to some Entity type. Each entity has an assigned ID (In my example I used `long` for IDs, but the `Response` class can be made generic).

`DtoBase` class:

```
[DataContract]
public abstract class DtoBase
    : IDtoResponseEnvelop
{
    [DataMember]
    private readonly Response _responseInstance = new Response();

    //This constructor should be called when there is no result
    protected DtoBase()
    {}

    //Each DTO object relates to some Entity (each entity has as ID). 
    //And if there is some result this constructor should be called. 
    protected DtoBase(long entityId)
    {
        _responseInstance = new Response(entityId);
    }

    #region IDtoResponseEnvelop Members

    public Response Response
    {
        get { return _responseInstance; }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Basically, the `Response` class aggregates operation response information such as: if there is any value, exception and warnings:

```
[DataContract]
public class Response
{        
    #region Constructors

    public Response():this(0){}

    public Response(long entityId)
    {
        _entityIdInstance = entityId;
    }

    #endregion        

    #region Private Serializable Members

    [DataMember]
    private BusinessExceptionDto _businessExceptionInstance;

    [DataMember]
    private readonly IList<BusinessWarning> _businessWarningList = new List<BusinessWarning>();

    [DataMember]
    private readonly long _entityIdInstance;

    #endregion

    #region Public Methods

    public void AddBusinessException(BusinessException exception)
    {
        _businessExceptionInstance = new BusinessExceptionDto(exception.ExceptionType, exception.Message, exception.StackTrace);
    }

    public void AddBusinessWarnings(IEnumerable<BusinessWarning> warnings)
    {
        warnings.ToList().ForEach( w => _businessWarningList.Add(w));
    }

    #endregion

    #region Public Getters

    public bool HasWarning
    {
        get { return _businessWarningList.Count > 0; }
    }

    public IEnumerable<BusinessWarning> BusinessWarnings
    {
        get { return new ReadOnlyCollection<BusinessWarning>(_businessWarningList); }
    }

    public long EntityId
    {
        get { return _entityIdInstance; }
    }

    public bool HasValue
    {
        get { return EntityId != default(long); }
    }

    public bool HasException
    {
        get { return _businessExceptionInstance != null; }
    }

    public BusinessExceptionDto BusinessException
    {
        get { return _businessExceptionInstance; }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Now, having this in place, on server side we have:

```
    private UserDto GetUserByIdCommand(IRepositoryLocator locator, long userId)
    {
        var item = locator.GetById<User>(userId);
        if (item != null) 
             return Mapper.Map<User, UserDto>(item); //mapper calls UserDto(item.ID) constructor

        _businessNotifier.AddWarning(BusinessWarningEnum.Operational,
            string.Format("User with Id=\"{0}\" not found", userId));
        return new UserDto(); //no Entity id is provided here, since no value available
    }
```

And, on client side:

```
    var userDto = UserService.GetUserById(1);
    if(!userDto.Response.HasValue)
    {
          //No result is available
    }
```

Is my approach fine or is there a better way?

Comment: I think it would be more natural to return a generic response object (Response<UserDTO>) that contains the DTO result as a property. It just seems more straightforward to reason about a response that has the result that you want, rather than returning a result then checking the response to see if the result actually has anything.

Answer (score 5):

I only quickly glanced at your code, so this isn't going to be a thorough review, but I think the basic idea is surprising:

> Service never returns null or throws exceptions.

I think this approach is error-prone. When I call a method called `GetUserById`, for an `Id` that doesn't exist, I expect either an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` (or similar), or a `null` return value - **the last thing I expect** is a valid object filled up with default values filling up all members.

As @jlnorsworthy mentioned in his excellent comment, your approach is far from instinctive. Instead of:

```
var userDto = UserService.GetUserById(1);
if(!userDto.Response.HasValue)
{
      //No result is available
}
```

I would perfer to have:

```
var userResult = UserService.GetUserById(1);
if(userResult.Result == null)
{
      //No result is available
}
```

Also `HasValue` confusing because it is a well-known member of `Nullable<T>`, so I'd consider changing `EntityId` to be `Nullable<long>` or `Nullable<Int64>`:

```
public bool HasValue
{
    get { return EntityId.HasValue; }
}
```

---

What is `IRepositoryLocator`? If it is what I think it is, you should read up on [Mark Seeman's blog](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorisanAnti-Pattern/). Shortly put:

> Service Locator is a well-known pattern, and since it was described by Martin Fowler, it must be good, right?
>
> No, it's actually an **anti-pattern** and should be avoided.

---

Little nitpick, I wouldn't use `ForEach` here:

```
public void AddBusinessWarnings(IEnumerable<BusinessWarning> warnings)
{
    warnings.ToList().ForEach( w => _businessWarningList.Add(w));
}
```

It would be much more readable (and less [semantically controversial](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7816840/1188513)) to write it like this:

```
public void AddBusinessWarnings(IEnumerable<BusinessWarning> warnings)
{
    _businessWarningList.AddRange(warnings);
}
```

Comment: +1 In Java I tend to offer two versions of any single-object finder method: `findByFoo` returns `null` when none match whereas `getByFoo` throws an exception. This gives the client programmer the freedom to handle a missing item gracefully or fail as needed. While the two methods require a little more code, they can greatly increase DRY in many cases.